# Trying to get objects as list out of database gives "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to get a list out of my database using following code:

```
public ICollection<MatchGame> FindByAwayTeam(Team awayTeam)
        {
            return matchGames.Where(mg => mg.AwayTeam == awayTeam).ToList();
        }
```

This gives me following error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'SoccerManager1.Models.Domain.Team'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.

This is the domain class of the table in the db:

```
public class MatchGame
    {
        [Key]
        public int MatchGameId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
        public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Winner { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int HomeGoals { get; set; }
        public int AwayGoals { get; set; }
        public Boolean Draw { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsPlayed  { get; set; }

        public MatchGame(Team home, Team away, DateTime date)
        {
            HomeTeam = home;
            AwayTeam = away;
            Date = date;
            Draw = false;
            IsPlayed = false;
        }

        public MatchGame()
        {
        }
    }
```

I have never gotten this error before, so don't really have a clue of whats wrong, tried with Iqueryable instead of ICollection but same error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `Team` object cannot be translated into sql to use in the `WHERE` clause.

You have a couple of options:

1. You could just pull everything back from the database and then complete your linq query in memory with something like this:

   ```
   public ICollection<MatchGame> FindByAwayTeam(Team awayTeam)
   {
       return matchGames
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where(mg => mg.AwayTeam == awayTeam)
           .ToList();
   }
   ```

   The downside to this is that it pulls back every record from the database so incurs some extra unnecesary overhead (this may not be important or noticable if we are only talking about a few records).
2. You can use some identifier for `Team` that maps to a primitive. Usually you would have an `Id` field in the `Team` class too which leads to something like:

   ```
   public ICollection<MatchGame> FindByAwayTeam(Team awayTeam)
   {
       return matchGames
           .Where(mg => mg.AwayTeam.Id == awayTeam.Id)
           .ToList();
   }
   ```

Of the two approaches the second is by far the most preferable in terms of performance, future-proofing, etc.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend #2, as more often than not #1 will be a performance bottleneck. Even if there's not that many records *now*, that could very well change in the future and suddenly your app is running slow with no obvious cause. However, #1 is still technically an option.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Agreed. I'll update the answer to make that clear - I ordered them according to ease/similarity to the OPs approach rather than by preference.